# Access ctx property in layout in Nuxt app

Tags: nuxt.js

I developing an Nuxt app in ssr mode.

When I set `isMobile` property on the ctx using middleware I want to be able to access it in my layout.

The problem is that I think that nuxtServerInit is executed before the middleware so I can not commit the value to the vue store..

This is the middleware I use that sets isMobile on ctx:

```
export default function (ctx) {
   const userAgent = ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
   ctx.isMobile = /mobile/i.test(userAgent)
}
```

and this is how I tried to catch that info:

```
export const actions = {
   nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch }, ctx) {
      dispatch('app/setIsMobile', ctx.isMobile) // ctx.isMobile is always undefined
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to access ctx with my property inside my layout?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do that by simply dispatching to store from a middleware:

```
export default function ({ store, req }) {
   const userAgent = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
   const isMobile = /mobile/i.test(userAgent)
   dispatch('app/setIsMobile', isMobile)
}
```